# PostsgreSQL. How to return the number of records in the users table who have name Latifah, Elizabeth or Diana?

Tags: postgresql, count

I have this :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users
WHERE name = 'Latifah'
AND name = 'Elizabeth'
AND name = 'Diana';
```

It returns zero. What's wrong? Is there a way to make it shorter?

Comment: You used `or` in the question's title, but `and` in your query. At least this should ring a bell.

Comment: remove 'and' condition and put 'or'

Comment: I wouldn't put Elizabeth and Diana in the same room.

Comment: @pozs It's how the teacher formulated a question. he proably means and Diana. i will ask him.

Comment: @LenaK your teacher didn't formulate the question wrongly that way. No *user* can have `name = 'Latifah'` **and** `name = 'Elizabeth'` **at the same time**. That could only be possible if `'Latifah' = 'Elizabeth'` would be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can "aggregate" `OR`s to `IN` operator:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM users
WHERE name IN ('Latifah','Elizabeth','Diana');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also worked:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users
WHERE name = 'Latifah'
or name = 'Elizabeth'
or name= 'Diana';
```